# Notepad++ Search And Replace Multiple Text Lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have thousands of these in many different rules rules

```
edit 1698

set src-address "172.29.44.51/32"

set dst-address "172.29.44.67/32" 

set service "tcp-1022"

set service "tcp-1023"

set service "tcp-1090"

set service "tcp-1098-1102"

set service "tcp-115"

set service "tcp-123"

set service "tcp-13000"

set service "tcp-13001"

set service "tcp-14000"

set service "tcp-14001"

set service "tcp-15000"

set service "tcp-16000"

set service "tcp-1812"

set service "tcp-22"

set service "tcp-32770-32900"

set service "tcp-3307"

set service "tcp-3528"

set service "tcp-3600"

set service "tcp-4400-4500"

set service "tcp-4712-4715"

set service "tcp-5000"

set service "tcp-5000-5630"

set service "tcp-50023-50030"

set service "tcp-5632-7000"

set service "tcp-636"

set service "tcp-7500"

set service "tcp-7600"

set service "tcp-7650"

set service "tcp-7651"

set service "tcp-7900"

set service "tcp-8009"

set service "tcp-8093"

set service "tcp-8443"

set service "tcp-9000"

set service "tcp-9001"

set service "udp-1023"

set service "udp-1102"

set service "udp-123"

set service "udp-13001"

set service "udp-14000"

set service "udp-14000-14001"

set service "udp-161"

set service "udp-162"

set service "udp-177"

set service "udp-22"

set service "udp-389"

set service "udp-45600-45800"

set service "udp-5900"

set service "udp-7500"

set service "udp-8443"

set service "udp-9001"

set service "udp-920-940"

exit
```

i want it to collect all set service lines into one line to be like this example

```
set service "PING" "tcp-1022" "tcp-1023" "tcp-1090" "tcp-1098-1102" "tcp-115" "tcp-123" "tcp-13000" "tcp-13001" "tcp-14000" "tcp-14001" "tcp-15000" "tcp-16000" "tcp-1812" "tcp-22" "tcp-32770-32900" "tcp-3307" "tcp-3528" "tcp-3600" "tcp-4400-4500" "tcp-4712-4715" "tcp-5000" "tcp-5000-5630" "tcp-50023-50030" "tcp-5632-7000" "tcp-636" "tcp-7500" "tcp-7600" "tcp-7650" "tcp-7651" "tcp-7900" "tcp-8009" "tcp-8093" "tcp-8443" "tcp-9000" "tcp-9001" "udp-1023" "udp-1102" "udp-123" "udp-13001" "udp-14000" "udp-14000-14001" "udp-161" "udp-162" "udp-177" "udp-22" "udp-389" "udp-45600-45800" "udp-5900" "udp-7500" "udp-8443" "udp-9001" "udp-920-940"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a notepad++ only solution. It is using macros, because you say you have many different rule files.

1. Macro -> Start Recording, now everything is recorded to a macro

   1. First Replace to mark the start of a set service block:

      - Press Ctrl-Pos1, to go to the beginnig of current file.
      - Search -> Replace...:
        **Find What**: `^(?!set service).+?\r\nset service`
        **Replace With**: `\1first set service\3` 
        check **Regular Expression** in the lower left
      - Press Replace All
   2. Second Replace to join a set service block with the starting line:

      - Press Ctrl-Pos1, to go to the beginnig of current file.
      - Search -> Replace...:
        **Find What**: `\r\nset service`
        **Replace With**: ``  (nothing)
        check **Extended** in the lower left
      - Press Replace All
   3. Third Replace to remove the tag in the starting line:

      - Press Ctrl-Pos1, to go to the beginnig of current file.
      - Search -> Replace...:
        **Find What**: `^first set service`
        **Replace With**: `set service`
        check **Regular Expression** in the lower left
      - Press Replace All
2. Macro -> Stop Recording
3. Macro -> Save Current Recorded Macro, give it a name and create a keyboard shortcut for it.
4. Test the Macro. If it works, continue, else delete it and restart recording.

Now you can open all your rule files and apply the Macro to each file.
If you need to delete the macro, you find it under Macro -> Modify Shortcut/Delete Macro.

**Edit:** here is a screenshot to debug the problems with the zero matches you write about in the comments: [image: screenshot with a part of the regexp], please note the marked sections:

- `\r\n` in the Find expression
- Dos\Windows as lineending type in the status bar
- Regular expression is checked in the lower left
- the region that is matched by the search in the file area

*The number of lines have to be modified*:

[image: The number of lines have to be modified]

*The result of suggested search Regex*:

[image: The result of suggested search Regex]

Comment: i tried it but once i click replace all it gives me " replace all:0 occurance were replaced"

Comment: That means that the search is not working. Please make sure that you have checked Extended in the lower left of the replace dialog. That makes sure that \r\n matches Dos\Windows lineendings. If you are using Unix lineendings please replace \r\n with only \n in the search. Notepad++ shows the kind of Lineendings in the Statusbar on the right.

Comment: In a comment above you stated that there are many set service blocks per file. That means that the answer with a single macro run per file will not work. I will try to think of an regex.

Comment: I changed the instructions to cope with several blocks per file.

Comment: when i have tried first step still the result the same " replace all:0 occurrence were replaced" - I'm using windows with notepad++

Comment: @Sentoki : I added a screenshot of the find dialog. If that does not help, please add a similar screenshot from your situation, showing the lines from the file (please activate View -> Show Symbols -> Show all symbols before) and the Search/Replace dialog where you have entered the strings.

Comment: i have added screenshot , a big number difference between the two counts , regex and only set service search .

Comment: Your lines are not seperated by an empty line as your example from the question suggested. So the regex must use only \r\n not \r\n\r\n. I will modify my answer.